# Trailing Flat buttons Overflows in ListTile

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` with `ListTile`. Each `ListTile` has a title with `Text`, subtitle with `Text`, and trailing  with two `Flatbuttons` into a `Column`. But the Flatbuttons overflows the ListTitle. How can I make sure that the FlatButtons stays within the bounds?

[image: FlatButtons overflows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need flatbutton in this case or is it better to use IconButton()?
Anyways remember that Flat buttons have a minimum size of 88.0 by 36.0 which can be overridden with [ButtonTheme].

And remember also that the heights of the leading and trailing widgets are constrained according to the Material spec. An exception is made for one-line ListTiles for accessibility.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html

eg:

```
ButtonTheme(
  minWidth:60,
  height:40
  child:FlatButton(
    child:Text("HelloWorld")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Expanded

```
  trailing: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      Expanded(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('text'),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```